# Jakarta Validation and Spring Boot - How to get field name in ConstraintViolationException?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
@Validated
public class PersonController {

  @GetMapping
  public List<Person> get(@RequestParam @Size(min= 3) String city){
    return List.of(new Person("Henrique " + city));
  }
}
```

When the client sends a request with the attribute city that has a size smaller than 3, the controller throws a `ConstraintViolationException`.

When this exception is thrown, I want the service to return a body containing the name of the field that has a validation error, in this example, the field is `city`. In order to do this, I created the following controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Error> 
  handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex){
      List<ErrorDetail> details =
            ex.getConstraintViolations().stream()
                    .map(e -> new ErrorDetail(e.getPropertyPath().toString(), e.getMessage()))
                    .toList();

      return new ResponseEntity<>(new Error(ex.getMessage(), details), BAD_REQUEST);
  }

}
```

However, the return that I get is the following:

```
{
  "message": "get.arg0: size must be between 3 and 2147483647",
  "details": [
      {
          "field": "get.arg0",
          "description": "size must be between 3 and 2147483647"
      }
  ]
}
```

How can I change the code so it returns the field name `city` instead of `get.arg0`?

A running example of this is available in https://github.com/henriquels25/spring-boot-validation-sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace `arg0` with `city` in the path, you need add the `-parameters` flag when compiling. That will include the parameter name in compiled code, which makes it available for reflection.

Comment: if you are using GRADLE and you have this specific issue, you need to include THIS in your config, as:
compileJava.options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'
compileTestJava.options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible for your use case to accept a request body instead of a request parameter or a path variable, then you can easily achieve this like so:

1. Create an object City:

   ```
   public class City {

   @Size(min = 3)
   String name;

      ...
   }
   ```
2. Modify the mapping method in your controller to accept the request body and add the @Valid annotation:

   ```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/people")
    @Validated
    public class PersonController {

    @GetMapping()
    public List<Person> get(@Valid @RequestBody City city) {
       return List.of(new Person("Henrique " + city.getName()));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Extend your handler class with the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` interface and override the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` method. Exceptions of type `ConstraintViolationException` will get handled by this method. Now you can use `MethodArgumentNotValidException` and access the object's affected fields:

   ```
    @ControllerAdvice
    public class ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatusCode status, WebRequest request) {

    List<FieldError> fields = ex.getFieldErrors();
    for (FieldError error : fields) {
        System.out.println("Affected field of the object is: " + error.getField());
    }

    String field = ex.getFieldError().getField();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(field, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@henriquels, kindly change your ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler class file with the below code , hopefully you will get what you desired for.

```
package io.sicredi.poc.restvalidation.handler;


import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Error> handleConstraintViolationException(ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        List<ErrorDetail> details = ex.getConstraintViolations().stream().map(e -> new ErrorDetail(e.getPropertyPath().toString().split("\\.")[1], e.getMessage())).toList();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Error(ex.getMessage().split("\\.")[1], details), BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue while running Gradle, you need to include this in your gradle config:

compileJava.options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'

compileTestJava.options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'